# How to integrate different installation packages into single execution file in Python

Tags: python, build, installation, cross-platform, executable

I have project which contains about 20 packages which are required to be installed in Python, to support all commands in code. And I want whole project to be single file which contains inside all relevant installations and program code itself. So to need only run this file, and all desired behaviour happens automatically. I need to create a build for Windows, and for MacOS.

1. What are available tools for creating a build of same program into single file - one (*.exe) file for Windows, and one (*.dmg) file for MacOS, for Python application both?
2. Is there an implementation option to unify into single installation file - for both Windows and MacOS operating systems? If yes - please explain how.
3. I use PyCharm as development environment. Is there an option to make a build from PyCharm? Do I need a PyCharm to be installed at all to be able to create installation wizard?